# How to implement a progressbar in index.html using Shiny when a long calculation is performed

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to implement something like a progress bar to use while the value of some function is being estimated. The function takes a long time to process. Is there any way to send some indicator from server.R that the function is completed, so I could hide the progress bar in index.html file. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/>
</head>
<body onload="progressbar.style.display='none';">
<table><tbody>
     <tr>
        <td align="right" ><label>Sample Input:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ns" value="10" title="Sample Size"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input class="button" type="submit" id="calc" name="calc" value="Calculate"  onclick="progressbar.style.display='block';"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right" ><label id="result"> Power:</label></td>
        <td ><div id="sampleSize" class="shiny-text-output" ></div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td><progress id="progressbar" value="50" max="100" ></progress> </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

My server.R file looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
data <- reactive({
    ns<-as.numeric(input$ns)
})

## set variable on loading the page
firstTime <- TRUE

# Generate an output
output$sampleSize <- renderText({

 ## get the data
 data<-data()
 if (!firstTime) {

    ## execute some long function
    Sys.sleep(5)

    ## return the output value from the above function
    return(as.character(data[1]))
 }
 else{
    firstTime<<-FALSE ## supress output on loading the page
    return(NULL)
 }
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to have a progress bar running until server.R posts back to your page?

One possible solution to this is using your own [custom bindings](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-inputs). You will want to hide your progress bar when `output$sampleSize()` is finished, so we will bind an output binding to that. Output bindings are explained in the Shiny [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-outputs).

You need to give your output `div` a new class *instead* of `shiny-text-output` e.g.:

```
<div id="sampleSize" class="sampler"></div>
```

Now the binding (add this code in as an external .js script or on the page in script tags):

```
var some_binding = new Shiny.OutputBinding();
$.extend(some_binding, {
  find: function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find('.sampler');
  },
  renderValue: function(el, data) {

    // Populate your div with output.
    $(el).text(data);

    // Hide your progress bar.
    $('#progressbar').hide();

  }
});

Shiny.outputBindings.register(some_binding, "someone.some_binding");
```

Now as `sampleSize` is being given a value to display the progress bar also gets hidden. This is highly untested but the general method should work.