# Shiny: How to display the progress information from a time-consuming function when it running

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a function may take more than 10mins and want to dynamically output some progress information to UI. I write a test script which using a demo in the shiny website as reference, but it not works.

Server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  logfilename<-"logfile.txt"
  MyFunc(logfilename)

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    unlink(logfilename)
  })

  fileReaderData <- reactiveFileReader(500, session,logfilename, readLines)

  output$fileReaderText <- renderText({
    text <- fileReaderData()
    length(text) <- 10
    text[is.na(text)] <- ""
    paste(text, collapse = '\n')
  })

  MyFunc<-function(logfile){
    for(i in 1:20){
      Sys.sleep(10);
      cat(i, '\n', file = logfile,append = TRUE);
    }
  }
})
```

UI.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("reactivePoll and reactiveFileReader"),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, p("The log file is appended to every second."))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, wellPanel(
      "This uses a reactiveFileReader, which is monitoring the",
      "log file for changes every 0.5 seconds.",
      verbatimTextOutput("fileReaderText")
    ))
  )
))
```

Look forward your help, thanks.

Comment: Maybe the progress indicator of shiny incubator package does what you want http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tags/shiny-incubator/

Comment: A different method was discussed in a similar question, [how to implement a progressbar in index.html using shiny when a long calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405077/how-to-implement-a-progressbar-in-index-html-using-shiny-when-a-long-calculation).