# Iterative text update after button press

Tags: r, shiny

I would like a status `textOutput` to iteratively update after sub-functions are complete. I am aware of [withProgress](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/withProgress.html), but I would like this to appear in the `textOutput`.

I believe because shiny is mono-threaded, the following does not work (i.e., render iteratively).

```
library(shiny)

ui<-(fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("res1"),
  actionButton("submit","Submit")
))


server<-(function(input, output,session) {

observeEvent("submit",{

  status_text = c("starting...")
  output$res1 = renderText(status_text)
  Sys.sleep(1)
  status_text = c(status_text," continuing...")
  output$res1 = renderText(status_text)
  Sys.sleep(2)
  status_text = c(status_text,"done")
  output$res1 = renderText(status_text)

  })

})

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Additionally, I have not had success with `renderText` checking for variables that are set during the loading process. I believe `invalidateLater()` could help but I also was not able to get it properly working.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405077/how-to-implement-a-progressbar-in-index-html-using-shiny-when-a-long-calculation

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, hopefully there is an easier solution than using custom bindings, but will definitely keep in mind regardless

Comment: Well, the easy solution is `withProgress()`, but since you have this very specific UI requirement, things are going to get tricky.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, i actually re-did aspects of the app to make withProgress() the feasible solution.